# Django Rest Framework list missing records

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have set up a Django Rest Framework (v.1.11.7) Viewset called CustomerViewset. It's as simple as follows:

```
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Customer.objects.all()
  serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
```

The serializer looks like:

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Customer
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'zone', 'website', 'email', 'slug', 'active', 'description', 'primary_color', 'nif', 'country', 'city', 'zip_code', 'address_1', 'address_2', 'address_3', 'telephone', 'allow_delete')
```

And the model:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(
    max_length=256
  )
  zone = models.ForeignKey(
    Zone,
    null=True,
    blank=True
  )
  active = models.BooleanField(
    default=True
  )
  allow_delete = models.BooleanField(
    default=True
  )
  logo = models.ImageField(
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    upload_to="customer/logo"
  )
  description = models.TextField(
    blank=True
  )
  website = models.URLField(
    blank=True
  )
  email = models.EmailField(
    blank=True
  )
  telephone = models.CharField(
    max_length=256,
    null=True,
    blank=True
  )
  slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
  nif = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
  country = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
  city = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
  zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
  address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
  address_2 = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
  address_3 = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
  primary_color = models.CharField(max_length=7, default="#F8F9FA")
```

This should work with no problem, however after a change (update or partial-update) is made to a Customer object, the particular object that was updated won't be listed again. The update payload that causes the trouble has the next structure:

```
active  true
address_1   null
address_2   null
address_3   null
allow_delete    true
city    null
country null
description 
email   
id  818
name    'Name test'
nif null
primary_color   '#F8F9FA'
slug    'name-test'
telephone   null
website 
zip_code    null
zone    1
```

Not even restarting the server (caché issues). But it still can be retrieved. No errors displayed on console or logs; it simply ignores the record when listing.

By overriding the `get_queryset` of the Viewset I can do the following:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
      queryset = Customer.objects.all()
      c = Customer.objects.get(id=818)
      print(c)
      _c = queryset.filter(id=818)
      print(_c)
      return queryset
```

818 is the id of the updated record. It does find the by filtering against  both, the queryset and the Customer model. But still, it's not on the list!

This is really weird and don't know what I'm missing here. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that possible to view those updated items through Django Admin?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge yes, they are still available through the Django Admin, with no corrupt data in the database (postgreSQL). I can also access them individually by retrieving them using my API.

Comment: did you defined any `get_queryset()` method in your view ?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge no, no `get_queryset()` defined.

Comment: can you update your question with models.py and your update payload ?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge updated with the payload, model and added the full fields array from the serializer.